# Unable to connect on tor network error 0.0.2.0:0? i am using a proxy server in college, the bridges obtained are not working.... below are the logs i

Tags: whonix

```
09/11/2016 12:45:39 PM.600 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
09/11/2016 12:45:39 PM.600 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
09/11/2016 12:45:39 PM.600 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
09/11/2016 12:45:39 PM.600 [NOTICE] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
09/11/2016 12:45:47 PM.600 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 5%: Connecting to directory server 
09/11/2016 12:45:47 PM.600 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server 
09/11/2016 12:45:47 PM.800 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 54.85.16.112:40872 ("general SOCKS server failure") 
09/11/2016 12:45:47 PM.800 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 52.53.248.234:59814 ("general SOCKS server failure") 
09/11/2016 12:45:49 PM.400 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 194.132.208.8:20438 ("general SOCKS server failure") 
09/11/2016 12:50:59 PM.800 [NOTICE] Closing no-longer-configured Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
09/11/2016 12:50:59 PM.800 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
09/11/2016 12:50:59 PM.800 [NOTICE] Closing old Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150
```

Answer (score 1):

This case indicates one of the things:

- **You have specified the proxy settings wrong** It happens when you've mistyped in `torrc` specifying your proxy server address, port and credentials. Just check it - if it's all fine and you can use a web browser with these specific settings, then it's not the case
- **Your proxy server requires some additional auth tokens** Like a Windows domain login, Kerberos ticket(for Microsoft products it can be a case). Try using some connection wrapper like an itermediate proxy of your own to see the logs and exact connection flow. It helps to save time guessing what exactly is going wrong. You use it for a web browser first - checking that this proxy chain is actually working and having a "positive" workflow. Then try to use Tor through your proxy and troubleshoot and/or identify the problem precisely.
- **Your proxy is blocking by-ip-basis Tor directory servers and/or bridge IPs** It's a censorship, try to use bridges(maybe, set up your own) that **don't** publish their identity in BridgeDB. Also try pluggable transports like Obfs 3 and 4